# OptaPlanner as a Domain Specific Task in jBPM?

Tags: drools, jbpm, optaplanner

I am trying to integrate an optaplanner project with jbpm6. I have put the optaplanner java project as a synchronous domain specific node. All the java classes, solverconfig.xml and .drl file has been exported to a JAR file in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\jbpm-console.war\WEB-INF\lib\ . However when I execute the process,it says that the solver configuration (solverconfig.xml) does not exist. I am assuming this is because, the xml file in the JAR cannot be read. I have read that there is an alternative to create the solver configuration as a java file (which is highly not recommended).

Is there any other approach I could take to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Can you copy the full path to your solver config xml and also copy the java code that you use to create the SolverFactory? I think it might just be a typo somewhere, as it should work.

Comment: From eclipse, the path of the SolverConfig.xml is

`/OptaPlannerProject/src/main/resources/CaseAssignmentSolverConfig.xml `
      
And the code to build the SolverFactory

`SolverFactory solverFactory = new XmlSolverFactory("/CaseAssignmentSolverConfig.xml"); Solver solver= solverFactory.buildSolver(); `

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if the jar in that lib folder indeed contains the `CaseAssignmentSolverConfig.xml` file.

2) In your java code, before you build the SolverFactory, try

```
getClass().getResource("/CaseAssignmentSolverConfig.xml")
```

it should not be null.

Side note: this all presumes you're using optaplanner 6.0 (for 6.1 the leading "/" will need to dissappear, but ignore this note for now).

Comment: I have used 'String url =this.getClass().getResource("/CaseAssignmentSolverConfig.xml").toString();' before building the SolverFactory. But it returns a null in the workbench. And the xml file is there in the jar package in the resource folder.

Comment: Because it returns `null` without optaplanner-core, it won't work inside optaplanner-core too. That means that the ClassLoaders are different, or that that jar in the lib folder isn't included in the classpath.
Although its possible to load the solver config xml file from a File or an InputStream (instead of a resource), that's won't fix it, because your domain classes still need to come from your jar, and therefore need to be available in the classloader. So they only fix is fixing the classloader/classpath issue.

Comment: I have got it running Geoffrey!! I copied the xml file and the drl file outside the resources folder in the jar file and it seemed to work.